# Vim plugin pytest not found

Tags: vim, pytest

I'm having trouble installing a vim plugin and don't really know where to begin troubleshooting.  I have dozens of other plugins installed okay using vundle, but I'm not sure why I can't get this one to, so I don't necessarily think my question is pytest.vim specific, so any general tips on troubleshooting these sorts of issues appreciated!

I've installed the vim plugin pytest by using vundle and adding the following to my ~/.vimrc:

```
Bundle 'alfredodeza/pytest.vim'
```

and doing a `BundleInstall!`

The plugin is installed in ~/.vim/bundle/pytest.vim but if I try and use :Pytest I just get `E492: Not an editor command: Pytest`

I can do a `:h pytest`.

I've restarted vim, and tried doing a vundle clean.

It's Vim 7.3 in a terminal, on Ubuntu 13.04.

Thanks!

Comment: You must put the line `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc. Reread the Vundle installation instructions.

Comment: Thanks.  I do have that in my vimrc.  I've been using vundle fine with dozens of other plugins fine for some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rebooted, cleared out eveyrthing, and reinstalled my plugins, and now it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the documentation is available shows that the Vundle install went fine. This plugin is a *filetype plugin* for Python (it resides in `ftplugin/`, not the usual `plugin/` subdir); therefore the plugin only works when:

1. You're editing a Python file (`:set filetype?` prints `python`; if not, `:setf python`)
2. As glts already commented, you must have at least `filetype plugin on` in your `~/.vimrc` to activate the filetype mechanism.

Comment: Thanks.  :set filetype? showed python, and I had filetype on.

I just rebooted, cleared out eveyrthing, and reinstalled bit by bit, and now it's working.  So who knows?!  Thanks!